# How to get proper permission on facebook to request user email?

Tags: facebook

here is an example with proper permissions. if I open it in browser I can get access to images and email.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?
    type=user_agent&
    client_id=116122545078207&
    redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbenbiddington.wordpress.com&
    scope=user_photos,email,user_birthday,user_online_presence
```

But when I execute the same url but with my client_id I don't get image, email just birthday information

What is the difference between? How can I get proper permissions to prompt user to provide image and email?

Comment: Basically I would like to add the code above to my button, just replace with my ID and redirect url to my website

Answer (score 5):

```
<fb:login-button perms='email, user_photos, user_birthday, user_online_presence' autologoutlink='true'></fb:login-button>
```

After Edit

You can read more information about [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) From here.

Again Edit.
You can find here some live example of [C# SDK](https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk)

Comment: It's returning - Invalid App
The app you are trying to use does not exist or has been disabled.

Comment: you are integrating facebook in you website or developing an application in facebook?

Comment: I would like to integrate Facebook Connect to my website. So I created application at Facebook dev to get all necessary codes

Comment: Can you please provide your code that you are using so that error can be found

Comment: My original question was about permission difference. Can someone help me to find answer?

Comment: I am just asking how you are retreiving your images and email from user. Can you provide us the code

Comment: There is no difference. They are all extended permissions.

Comment: var api = new Facebook.Rest.Api(_connectSession);
Facebook.Schema.user u = api.Users.GetInfo();
var image = u.pic_square;
var name = u.name;

Comment: Bro bro bro you are using old rest api. Facebook has deprecated most of the methods of Old Rest API. You should use now Graph API

Comment: See my answer again. I have edited it now. Hope you will find a good way to accomplish your job

Comment: I couldn't find any working examples using Graph Facebook Connect in Asp.Net C#

Comment: my dear at that link there is way to get permissions and user data. Then you have to parse data. Facebook gives data in json. You just need to parse data then from json code

Comment: now see again my answer. I have given link. Download C# SDK and enjoy some example

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution use this code it may help you

```
<html>

  <head></head>

  <body>

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="login">Connect My Account With Facebook</a>

  <br>

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="logout">logout Facebook</a>

  <br />

  <div id='user-info'></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>

  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
 // initialize the library with the API key

  FB.init({ apiKey: 'da21de4c85b58a0a510267aca5e17449',appId:'139950472740638'});

  

  // fetch the status on load

  FB.getLoginStatus(handleSessionResponse);

  

  $('#login').bind('click', function(){FB.login(handleSessionResponse);});

  

  $('#logout').bind('click', function() {FB.logout(handleSessionResponse);});

  

  $('#disconnect').bind('click', function() {

  FB.api({ method: 'Auth.revokeAuthorization' }, function(response) {

  clearDisplay();

  });

  });

  

  

  

  // handle a session response from any of the auth related calls

  function handleSessionResponse(response) 

  {

  // if we dont have a session, just hide the user info

  if (!response.session) {clearDisplay();   return;}

  

  FB.ui({

  method: 'permissions.request',

  perms: 'email' 

  },

  function (response)

  {

  FB.api({

  method: 'fql.query', 

  query: 'SELECT name,email,uid FROM user WHERE uid=' + FB.getSession().uid 

  },

  function(response2) 

  {

  var user = response2[0]; 

  $('#user-info').html(user.name +' -- '+ user.email +' -- '+ user.uid).show('fast'); 

  }

  );

  }

  

  ); 

  

  }

  </script>


</body>

  </html>
```